# php form action failed to work

Tags: php, mysql, validation, redirect, action

am using xampp, and one of my processing php files in in C:xampp/htdcos/Loan Management/includes/conf_login.php
but every time I try to login I get an error
that the ridirecting page link is either outdated or does not exits. what should I do?
this page confirms Log ins and redirects to the selected page

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: william
 * Date: 6/21/14
 * Time: 9:25 PM
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="css/new_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Stanbic Bank E-Banking:Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="../includes/conf_login.php" method="post">
    <div class="row toprow">
    <!--changes done by keerthana for login page header start -->
        <div id="header">
            <div class="header-main_cus">
                <div class="wrapper_cus">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="logo_cus">
                            <a><img src="images/u7_normal.txt" alt="Standard bank Logo"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="width100percent_loginbg_cus">
            <div class="width20percent_left_cus">
                <p id="HDisplay1.Rb7" class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="ForgotPassword" title="ForgotPassword" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"></span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_cus" title="Forgot Password">
                            <a href="#" title="Forgot Password" class="bluelink_cus">Forgot Password</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Stanbic Bank Home Page" title="Stanbic Bank Home Page" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"></span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_cus" title="Stanbic Bank Home Page">
                            <a href="home.php" title="Stanbic Bank Home Page" class="bluelink_cus">Stanbic Bank Home Page</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"></span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_cus">
                            <a href="home.php?page=account" class="bluelink_cus">Account activation</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"></span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_cus"><a href="#"  class="bluelink_cus">FAQs</a></span>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="width60percent_login_cus">
                <div class="loginrow1_topborder_login_cus">
                    <div class="login_color_cus">Login</div>
                </div>
                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span>
                        <label for="AuthenticationFG.USER_PRINCIPAL" title="Username" class="bluetext_cus">Username :</label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="width70right_cus">
                        <span class="labelColumn">
                            <input name="user" title="Username" size="28" class="querytextboxmedium type_UserPrincipal"  maxlength="32" type="text">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span><label for="AuthenticationFG.ACCESS_CODE" title="Password" class="bluetext_cus">Password :</label></span>
                    <span class="width70right_cus">
                        <span class="labelColumn"><input name="upass" size="28" class="querytextboxmedium" title="Password" type="password"></span>
                        <span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span><label for="AuthenticationFG.MENU_ID" title="Option" class="bluetext_cus">Option :</label></span>
                    <span class="width70right_cus">
                        <span class="labelColumn_combo">
                            <span class="labelColumn_combo_brdr">
                                <select name="page" class="dropdownexpandalbe">
                                    <option value="userprofile">Dashboard</option>
                                    <option value="accpayments">Payments</option>
                                    <option value="currentaccount">Account Services</option>
                                    <option value="loanmgt">Loan Services</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span>
                        <img src="images/HintIcon1.gif" alt="Hints" title="Hints" class="hintimage1_cus" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" title="Hints:">Hints:</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" title="Your password is caSe sEnsiTive - Check your Caps lock">Your password is case sensitive Check your CAPS LOCK </span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_login2_cus">
                    <span class="width10right_cus">
                        <span class="HW_formbtn">
                            <input name="submit" class="formbtn"  alt="Login" title="Login" value="Login" type="Submit">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="HW_formbtn">
                            <input name="Action.Reset" class="formbtn" value="Clear" title="Clear" type="Reset">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <br/>
                <p class="loginrow1_bottomborder_login2_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_display_cus" title="By logging on I acknowledge that I have read, understood and I am bound by the version of the Electronic Banking Agreement that is posted at the website at the time of logging on.">By logging on I acknowledge that I have read, understood and I am bound by the version of the</span>
                        <span class="simpletext_display_link_cus" title="By logging on I acknowledge that I have read, understood and I am bound by the version of the Electronic Banking Agreement that is posted at the website at the time of logging on.">Electronic Banking Agreement</span>
                        <span class="simpletext_display_cus" title="By logging on I acknowledge that I have read, understood and I am bound by the version of the Electronic Banking Agreement that is posted at the website at the time of logging on.">that is posted at the website at the time of logging on.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_less_height_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_withborder_cus">
                    <span>
                        <img src="images/sign.jpg" alt="Security" title="Security" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"><span class="redtext_cus" title="Important security alert!">Important security alert!</span>
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" title="Stanbic Bank will never ask you to access internet banking through a link in an email. Dont fall victim to fraud!">Stanbic Bank will never ask you to access internet banking through a link in an email. Dont fall victim to fraud!</span>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/learn-more.gif" alt="LearnMore" title="LearnMore" class="hintimage_cus" border="0">
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_less_height_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_topborder_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="bluetext_cus" title="Customer Alert!!! [Beware of phishing]">Customer Alert!!! [Beware of phishing]</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span>
                        <img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Do not respond to fraudulent communications asking for your credentials such as Account Number, Password, User id and Card Number." title="Do not respond to fraudulent communications asking for your credentials such as Account Number, Password, User id and Card Number." class="hintimage_cus" id="Image5878753" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" id="Caption5499373" title="Do not respond to fraudulent communications asking for your credentials such as Account Number, Password, User id and Card Number.">Do not respond to fraudulent communications asking for your credentials such as Account Number, Password, User id and Card Number.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span>
                        <img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Fraudulent e-mails contain links of look-alike websites to mislead into entering sensitive financial data." title="Fraudulent e-mails contain links of look-alike websites to mislead into entering sensitive financial data." class="hintimage_cus" id="Image3855381" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" id="Caption8169444" title="Fraudulent e-mails contain links of look-alike websites to mislead into entering sensitive financial data.">Fraudulent e-mails contain links of look-alike websites to mislead into entering sensitive financial data.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span>
                        <img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Under no circumstances will the Bank send such communications to customers asking for their personal or confidential information." title="Under no circumstances will the Bank send such communications to customers asking for their personal or confidential information." class="hintimage_cus" id="Image5095426" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" id="Caption11258094" title="Under no circumstances will the Bank send such communications to customers asking for their personal or confidential information.">Under no circumstances will the Bank send such communications to customers asking for their personal or confidential information.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Always visit Bank's Authenticated Website instead of clicking on the links provided in emails or third party websites." title="Always visit Bank's Authenticated Website instead of clicking on the links provided in emails or third party websites." class="hintimage_cus" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" title="Always visit Bank's Authenticated Website instead of clicking on the links provided in emails or third party websites.">Always visit Bank's Authenticated Website instead of clicking on the links provided in emails or third party websites.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="Do not respond to pop-up windows asking for your confidential information." title="Do not respond to pop-up windows asking for your confidential information." class="hintimage_cus" border="0">
                        <span class="bluetext1_cus" id="Caption29557099" title="Do not respond to pop-up windows asking for your confidential information.">Do not respond to pop-up windows asking for your confidential information.</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow1_left_right_border_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="width20percent_right_cus">

                <p class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/Demo.jpg" alt="Ebanking Demo" title="Ebanking Demo" class="demoImage" border="0" width="150"></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="bluetext_cus" title="Announcements">Announcements</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_cus">
                    <span><img src="images/bullet00.gif" alt="What's new?" title="What's new?" class="hintimage_cus" border="0"></span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_display_cus" title="What's New?">
                            <a href="#" title="What's New?" name="#" class="blacklink_cus">What's New?</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_less_height_cus">
                    <span><span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_top_bottomborder_cus">
                    <span><span class="bluetext_cus" title="Customer Services">Customer Services</span></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_cus">
                    <span><span class="bluetext1_cus" id="Caption6432116" title="E-mail:">E-mail:</span></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_cus">
                    <span>
                        <span class="simpletext_margin_cus"  title="CCCUG@stanbic.com"><a href="#" title="CCCUG@stanbic.com" name="#" class="blacklink_cus">CCCUG@stanbic.com</a></span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_less_height_cus">
                    <span><span class="simpletext">&nbsp;</span></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_cus">
                    <span><span class="bluetext1_cus" title="Customer Contact Center:">Customer Contact Center:</span></span>
                </p>

                <p class="loginrow_cus">
                    <span><span class="bluetext1_cus" title="+256417154910">+256417154910</span></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `action="../includes/conf_login.php"` is probarly wrong. Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: @Daan the page am redirecting to is in C:\xampp\htdocs\Loan Management\includes

Comment: And where does the script you posted stand?

Comment: on which page the above code lies? give full path..and give path from your root too

Comment: @Daan this page i posted lies in C:\xampp\htdocs\Loan Management\includes and the file am redirecting to is in the same folder

Comment: remove this : `../includes/`